# Ways of handling unknown data type in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a statement that executes a sql like this:

```
execute immediate cursor_rule.rule_sql into rule_result ;
```

my problem is that the output of rule_sql can be anything from null, to boolean to a number.

How do I define rule_result in a situation like this?

Comment: You can define it as `Varchar2` as it handles most of the case.

Comment: `rule_sql` can't be `boolean` because Oracle SQL doesn't support that datatype.

Comment: rule_sql is an sql that i will be executing.. could be as simple as 'select * from dual where 1>0' this gives a boolean output.

Comment: No, that doesn't give a Boolean output. That query would simply return no rows.

Comment: @APC: Oracle **does** support a boolean type in PL/SQL (but not in SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - My comment specifies SQL. And, as the OP's comments say they are executing SQL statements not PL/SQL blocks,  my comment stands.

Comment: @APC: `execute immediate` is clearly PL/SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - but the return value comes from the statement it executes: if the dynamic statement is SQL it cannot use `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
DECLARE
  rule_result VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :your_sql INTO rule_result;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL; -- Handle what should happen when the SQL returns zero rows.
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    NULL; -- Handle what should happen when the SQL returns two or more rows.
END;
/
```

If the result of your sql statement is a:

- String data type then it gets stored in the `rule_result` as is.
- numeric data type then Oracle will implicitly call [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) on it to convert it to a `VARCHAR2` value exactly long enough to hold its significant digits.
- `DATE` data type then Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR( date_value, NLS_DATE_FORMAT )` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model to convert it to a string.
- `TIMESTAMP` data type then Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR( timestamp_value, NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT )` using the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model to convert it to a string.

Comment: why not declare a variable using "type" or "rowtype" instead of VARCHAR2(4000) ?? this will always match to the correct datatype

Comment: @nabeel The OP is using dynamic SQL so they do not know which `COLUMN_NAME%TYPE` or `TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE` to define the variable as in the `DECLARE` part of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the SQL statement using DBMS_SQL to discover the column data type. For example:

```
declare
    l_cursor_id pls_integer := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    l_pointless_count pls_integer;
    l_desc_cols dbms_sql.desc_tab;
    l_sql long := 'select dummy as teststring, 123 as testnum, sysdate as testdate from dual';
begin
    dbms_sql.parse(l_cursor_id, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.describe_columns(l_cursor_id, l_pointless_count, l_desc_cols);

    for i in 1..l_desc_cols.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line
        ( rpad(l_desc_cols(i).col_name,31) || lpad(l_desc_cols(i).col_type,4) );
    end loop;

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_cursor_id);
end;
```

Output:

```
TESTSTRING                        1
TESTNUM                           2
TESTDATE                         12
```

Type codes are defined in [DBMS_TYPES](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_types.htm) and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) (which as I discovered last week do not necessarily agree).